# Keyboard to Laptop Cable

Tags: keyboard, homerecording

I have a Casio Privia PX-100, and a Dell laptop. The electronic piano has a MIDI input-output set, and TWO headphone jacks. The laptop has HDMI, USB, microphone, and headphone inputs/outputs. I am looking to record the SOUND of the piano - NOT MIDI. Two questions:

(1) Do I need a headphone splitter, or may I plug headphones into the remaining jack (while the other one is being used for recording)?

(2) My jack size is 3.5mm (1/8 inch). Will the following product work? Can I get anything better instead?
[https://www.amazon.com/3-5mm-8-Inch-Stereo-Audio-Cable/dp/B001QDB7R0/ref=pd_sim_23_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B001QDB7R0&pd_rd_r=QPKJC9BJX6393A47G5GH&pd_rd_w=7zZOk&pd_rd_wg=UrLxN&psc=1&refRID=QPKJC9BJX6393A47G5GH](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QDB7R0)

Thank you.

Comment: Over-simplifying, but the headphone output of the keyboard will be too 'hot' for the mic input of the lappy. by the time you turn it up enough to hear it properly in the headphones, you'll be cooking the mic input.

Comment: Computers with "basic" audio support and only one audio input usually have some way to attenuate the audio signal . Look in the taskbar icons or right click on the desktop for something called "audio setup" or "mixer." It might be an app written by Dell, not part of Windows itself.

Comment: ...yes, but even if you can get the levels right that doesn't mean you will get acceptable recording quality. Laptop mic inputs are notorious for being usually very low-quality. I recommend you get a proper interface – something cheap like Behringer U-Control or Miditech Audiolink should suffice. Regardless of what you do about the audio, I strongly recommend you _also_ record the MIDI. You may now think the sound of the Privia is fine, but on recordings those digital pianos often turn out to sound duller than expected, no match for highly dynamic sampled or simulated VSTs, e.g. Pianoteq.

Comment: Thank you @leftaroundabout - I will consider your recommendations.

Comment: Will this work? https://www.amazon.com/Behringer-UCA202-BEHRINGER-U-CONTROL/dp/B000KW2YEI And will the cable I linked in the original post connect to it?

Comment: FWIW i have had acceptable recording results plugging a headphone output into some laptops' inputs. I've also had laptops which had way too much noise on the inputs, but it's worth trying first. I find most "mic" inputs on computers are way too insensitive to work with most mics, and really seem more like line inputs anyway. One tip - if you find you are getting weird noises, try unplugging the laptop PSU and running on battery.

Answer (score 1):

Try.   There are plenty of reasons this might not work.  With the keyboard's output high enough to be audible in headphones connected to one socket, the level going to the computer may be unmanagably high.  The headphone output will be stereo (or at least fake-stereo) and may not suit a mono mic input.  But, an adapter cable is cheap, and I don't think you'll damage the computer input - start with the keyboard output low though when doing tests!

If the results are unacceptable, ask again.